# ttkbootstrap not working with pyinstaller

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, ttkbootstrap

With Python Interpreter it works fine, image loads and main.py runs without problems, but when I make it into one file .exe with Pyinstaller, .exe crashes with the following error message.

```
FileNotFoundError: 'themes.json' resource not found in 'ttkboostrap'
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue.

Head over to where your `ttkbootstrap` is installed, copy `themes.json` and `Symbola.ttf` (if required) to the same folder as your `main.py` and `main.spec`.

Then modify your `main.spec` with `datas=[('themes.json', 'ttkbootstrap'), ('Symbola.ttf', 'ttkbootstrap')]` under `a = Analysis()`.

`Symbola.ttf` may not be required for you but I encountered another FileNotFoundError after copying `themes.json` over to the folder, which required me to bring over `Symbola.ttf` as well.

Once done, run `pyinstaller main.spec` on elevated command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm not sure as to what you mean by "run `pyinstaller main.spec` on elevated command prompt". Should I run this command after running `pyinstaller main.py` or before?

Comment: Hi there, no need to run `pyinstaller main.py` at all, just run `pyinstaller main.spec` will do because what the `.spec` file will do is that it will instruct Pyinstaller on how to process your script with `a = Analysis(['main.py'], ...)`. More details here https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

Answer (score 2):

In your.spec file change as follows

datas=[('venv\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap', 'ttkbootstrap')],

hiddenimports=['ttkbootstrap']

important - check in ttkbootstrap FOLDER available in in your venv\Lib\site-packages

then run
pyinstaller -F your.spec

Comment: When i try to run `pyinstaller -F your.spec` it shows 
`  File "gui.spec", line 18
    noarchive=False)
                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: problem with your spec file.. its working command pyinstaller -F your.spec

Comment: Also do we do pyisntaller -F your.spec after doing pyinstaller -F main.py or after?

Comment: do after pyinstaller -F main.py

Comment: This solution worked for me but you need to use *double* backslashes (they're not displayed though present in answer, I guess it's escaped by SO).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

Try using the old version of ttkbootstrap.Version "0.5.2" worked in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Without changing .spec file simply add this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py --collect-all ttkbootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ok. I played around with this for a few minutes using pyinstaller and
> was able to get it to work. You need to add --collect-all ttkbootstrap
>
> You can read more about this option here:
> https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html
>
> Essentially, what you need to do with either pyinstaller or py2exe is
> make sure that it is importing all of the required files. This can be
> done is various ways depending on how you are building your
> executable. I'm not sure if the method below is the most efficient,
> but it does work.
>
> `C:\\> pyinstaller yourprogram.py --collect-all ttkbootstrap`

I saw this on here which worked out for me!

https://github.com/israel-dryer/ttkbootstrap/issues/43