# Pyinstaller not working well with ttkbootstrap library

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, ttkbootstrap

I have a simple GUI which I designed with `tkinter` & `ttkbootstrap`.

Everything works fine when I run the script with my IDE.

Also, The `main.exe` file is created successfully with `Pyinstaller` by using this command: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py`.

Finally I get this Information: `456865 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.`

**But** when I'm trying to run `main.exe` which located in: `C:\Users\benja\Desktop\simpleGUI\dist` I get this error:

[image]

I'll appreciate any help to solve this error.

Comment: Refer to [official document](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html) when you need to include files into executable.

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68181066/11255635